# Java Fullscreen Modal Dialogs

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, fullscreen, jdialog

How does one create a custom modal JDialog that can be used as an internal dialog? For use in FullscreenExclusiveMode.

I have a JScrollPane (with a huge scrollbar) full of huge buttons like so:

```
+----------------------+------+
|         FOO          |  /\  |
|______________________+------+
|                      |______|
|         BAR          |      |
|______________________|  ==  |
|                      |______|
|         BIZ          |      |
+______________________+------+
|                      |  \/  |
|----------------------+------+
```

I need the user to use the giant scrollbar to scroll through and tap a particular button to select it and close the dialog. The dialog is in fullscreen exclusive mode. The close button needs to be disabled and it needs to not have okay or cancel buttons, whichever button they click needs to update a value and then call frame.dispose() on the dialog.

Right now I'm using an internal frame but the frame isn't popping up in front of everything else because I'm not using a JDesktop. I've also tried JDialog but it minimizes the app.

JOptionPane.showInternalDialog() works but how do I construct my own internal dialogs in the same fashion so that they can be shown? If I make an internal frame and then add it to a component it just sits within that component and not on top of everything.

EDIT: Looked through those classes and tried the popup factory but the popups don't seem to work reliably in fullscreen.

EDIT: Trying JOptionPane.createInternalFrame() here is the demo I'm working with but it doesn't seem to be working yet.

```
public class FullscreenDialog {

    public static final void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());//uses os window manager

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Something to say.");
        panel.add(label);
        final JFrame fullscreenFrame = new JFrame();
        fullscreenFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fullscreenFrame.setUndecorated(true);//To remove the bars around the frame.
        fullscreenFrame.setResizable(false);//resizability causes unsafe operations.
        fullscreenFrame.setContentPane(panel);
        fullscreenFrame.validate();
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(fullscreenFrame);//actually applies the fullscreen.

        final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
        optionPane.add(new JLabel("Some alert"));
        final JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Press me.");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("worked");
                optionPane.setValue(button);
            }
        });
        JInternalFrame frame  = optionPane.createInternalFrame(panel, "Internal Dialog");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `message` argument to the `JOptionPane` constructor can be a `Component` as well as a string, e.g. it could be your `JScrollPane`.

To remove the standard buttons from the option pane, call `setOptions(Object[])` with an empty array.

Comment: Anyway to remove the window decorations or make it impossible to close with the x?

Comment: @dah, depends how you display it.  If you use `createDialog()` then try `setUndecorated(true)` on the resulting `JDialog`.

Comment: Hopefully I can just add in the action Listeners for those buttons this.getParent().getParent().hide() or .dispose()

Comment: @dah, if the dialog is modal then when you call `optionPane.setValue(nameOfThisButton)` from an ActionListener, the dialog will close.

Comment: This is all super useful. I was worried that I wouldn't be able to get a solution. Seems like not many people use swing for fullscreen apps.

Comment: createDialog() returns a JDialog and JDialogs won't work in fullscreen, the JOptionPane.showInternalDialog() works for basic dialogs because it is an internal frame.

Comment: createInternalFrame() though returns an internal frame! I'll be certain to check this out.

Answer (score 2):

JOptionPane.showXXXDialog(...) allows for a lot of customizations in creating a custom internal dialog.

Comment: I'm looking for like a modal frame, needs to have a ScrollPane with a bunch of large buttons in it.

Comment: @dah what is wrong with using JOptionPane? If you don't like it you can always create your own JDialog and use it in a similar fashion.

Comment: I don't think I can use JOptionPane with a bunch of complex components like a JScrollPane with like 20 (100x40 ) buttons within it. I also need to remove the OK and Cancel buttons. JDialog doesn't work in fullscreen mode. It causes the app to lose fullscreen mode and focus and returns me to the desktop, which since it is meant for a touchscreen interface that can only be terminated with the keyboard from remote desktop it is a major problem.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the okay and cancel buttons, disable the close button in the top right and pass it a JScrollPane to be the component in it's center?

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
.
.
.
            final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
            optionPane.add(new JLabel("Some alert"));
            final JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setText("Press me.");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setText("worked");
                    fullscreenFrame.invalidate();
                    fullscreenFrame.repaint();
                    optionPane.setValue(button);
                }
            });
            JInternalFrame frame  = optionPane.createInternalFrame(panel, "Internal Dialog");
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            pnl.add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
            pnl.add( new JScrollBar(), BorderLayout.CENTER );
            frame.getContentPane().add( pnl );
            frame.setVisible(true);
```